# Maya Pymel: pass fileDialog2's return to a UI textfield

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I'm having trouble understanding how to use fileDialog2's "optionsUICommit" flag. When the user hit's "save" in the file dialog box, I want to run the command `on_save_dialog_file`. But from the help file, it seems to want me to use a MEL command.

http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/index.html

> MEL only. The string is interpreted as a MEL callback, to be called
>   when the dialog is successfully dismissed. It will not be called if
>   the user cancels the dialog, or closes the window using window title
>   bar controls or other window system means. The callback is of the
>   form: global proc MyCustomOptionsUICommit(string $parent)
>
> The parent argument is the parent layout into which controls have been
>   added using the optionsUICreate flag

This seems...complicated.

Here's my code.

```
import pymel.core as pm


def on_save_dialog_file(myDialog):
    print "Hello from file_dialog_save_file()!"


def file_dialog_save_file():
    myDialog = pm.fileDialog2(ocm="on_save_dialog_file", fm=0, ff="Maya Files (*.ma *.mb);;Maya ASCII (*.ma);;Maya Binary (*.mb);;All Files (*.*)", dialogStyle=2)
    print myDialog


file_dialog_save_file()
```

Even trying as a weird Mel->Python command didn't work. `ocm="python \"on_save_dialog_file()\";"`

Is there an easier/more straightforward way to run a command after setting a save file in the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it like this, without the callback.  Anything other than a user selection will return `None`

```
c = cmds.fileDialog2(fm=0, ff="Maya Files (*.ma *.mb);;Maya ASCII (*.ma);;Maya Binary (*.mb);;All Files (*.*)", dialogStyle=2)
if c:
    print c
else:
    print "user cancelled"
```

Comment: Ugh, yes way simpler. Thank you @theodox!

Answer (score 1):

Something that cam up for me when dealing with FileDialog2 was the fact that it returns the path of the selected file/directory in an array. If you want to use the string value of the returned information you have to specify part of the array first.

```
c = mc.fileDialog2(fm=3, dialogStyle=2)
k = c[0]
print(str(k))
```